# Python numpy indexing does not work

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
dx = 8
dy = 10
bx = 5.34
by = 1.09
index = np.zeros((dx+dy),dtype = 'int32')
for i in np.arange(1,dy+1):
    for j in np.arange (1,dx+1):
        if i-by > 0:
            theta = 180*np.arctan(abs(j-bx)/(i-by))/np.pi
            if theta<10:
                r = np.around(np.sqrt((j-bx)**2+(i-by)**2))
                r = r.astype(int)               
                if r>0:
                    index[r]+=1
                    output = np.zeros((r, index[r]),dtype='int32')
                    output[r-1,index[r]-1] = i+(j-1)*dy
```

this code should use (r, index[r]) as indices and put the value of i+(j-1)*dy to the corresponding indices and record that in a new matrix/array which should look like this-

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [44,  0,  0],
   [45, 55,  0],
   [46, 56,  0],
   [47, 57,  0],
   [48, 58,  0],
   [39, 49, 59],
   [40, 50, 60]])
```

But I am having the output like this instead which I don't want-

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0, 60]])
```

Comment: There is probably a much more efficient way to set these values instead of using nested loops.  It would help if you would explain a bit more what the meaning of your output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell *what* your code is trying to do.  Is your desired output supposed to be `s`, `c`, or `index`?

Or, maybe you want to create a new array, I'll call it `output` and then you can set the value of `output` at `s` to `c` using: `output[s] = c`.

If you don't know the size in advance, then the best thing I can think of right now is keep track of all the index values in a list of `rows` and `cols`, and of the actual values in a list of `values`:

```
import numpy as np
dx = 8
dy = 10
bx = 5.34
by = 1.09
index = np.zeros(dx+dy,dtype = 'int32')
rows = []
cols = []
vals = []
for i in np.arange(2,dy+1):
    for j in np.arange(1,dx+1):
        theta = 180*np.arctan(abs(j-bx)/(i-by))/np.pi
        if theta < 10:
            r = np.around(np.sqrt((j-bx)**2+(i-by)**2))
            r = r.astype(int) 
            if r > 0:
                index[r] += 1
                rows.append(r-1)
                cols.append(index[r]-1)
                vals.append(i+(j-1)*dy)

outshape = max(rows)+1, max(cols)+1  # now you know the size
output = np.zeros(outshape, np.int)  
output[rows, cols] = vals
```

Then, `output` looks like this:

```
In [60]: output
Out[60]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [44,  0,  0],
       [45, 55,  0],
       [46, 56,  0],
       [47, 57,  0],
       [48, 58,  0],
       [39, 49, 59],
       [40, 50, 60]])
```

---

**If you know the size in advance:**

```
import numpy as np
dx = 8
dy = 10
bx = 5.34
by = 1.09
index = np.zeros(dx+dy,dtype = 'int32')
outshape = (nrows, ncols)                        # if you know the size
output = np.zeros(outshape, np.int)              # initialize the output matrix
for i in np.arange(2,dy+1):
    for j in np.arange(1,dx+1):
        theta = 180*np.arctan(abs(j-bx)/(i-by))/np.pi
        if theta < 10:
            r = np.around(np.sqrt((j-bx)**2+(i-by)**2))
            r = r.astype(int) 
            if r > 0:
                index[r] += 1
                output[r-1, index[r]-1] = i+(j-1)*dy  # no need to set `s` or `c`
```

Comment: @ askewchan - Hi, the way you solve is giving the right output. But I dont know the size of the output. The output size actually depends on (r,index[r]). In that case how can I define the output array so that it will make the output depending on the indice values of r,index[r].

Comment: so actually in this code r is radius within 20 degree(defined by theta<10), index is counting how many radius are there and output should positioned the index in a matrix.

Comment: Is there any way I can set the output like output = np.zeros(r,index[r]) so that it will create the output the exact size and use (r-1,index[r]-1) as indices and put the value of i+(j-1)*dy in the corresponding indices position of the output array which should give the exact output as you mentioned in your answer

Comment: I have edited the question what I tried later and still no luck. please have a look and thanks for your time

Comment: @user2095624 The problem with your edit (and using `r` to define the size) is that `r` changes with each loop, but you want to have only one `output`.  You want to try to find out what `max(rs)` and `max(index)` would be, and make the shape of your output array be `(max(rs), max(index))`.  If you use `np.zeros` inside your loop, you'll erase all the changes from previous loops.

Comment: thanx for your answer again. this works for me though I had to add +1 with max(rows).

Comment: @user2095624 Haha, I just fixed that a few minutes ago, and cleaned up a few other things.  Good luck!